# How to translate this inline assembly code to x64 assembly

Tags: c++, assembly

I have following  C++ function with inline assembly:

```
void getMemAddrFromBIOSbySMI(int& bResult, unsigned long& addr,unsigned long& dataLength){
    __asm {              
        mov eax, 0x000000E3               
        mov ebx, 0x00000001               
        mov ecx, 0xFAFAFAFA               
        mov edx, 0x000000B2              
        out dx,al               
        mov bResult, eax              
        mov addr,  ebx            
        mov dataLength, ecx        
    }

    if((bResult & 0x000000FF) == 0){
        bReSult = 1;        
    } 
    else { 
        bResult = 0;       
    }
}
```

I want to let this code can support x64, but VC++ x64 have no support inline assembly, I have no idea how to translate this code to x64 assembly format...

Have anybody can help me?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? Maybe an official way exists...

Comment: Hi, Seva : I want to use this code in kernel space, but vc++ x64 unsupport inline assembly, do you know any way or compiler intrinsic function can  equivalent it?

Comment: Build an assembly-only file. Use `ml` to compile it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the compiler intrinsic [__outbyte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yxkhewh.aspx) to write to a port.

Comment: Hi, Sean:
        I know, I also want this code in kernel space, but I hove no
        idea whether have any way  or intrinsic to equivalent mov 
        eax/ebx/ecx/edx and how to read data from  eax/ebx/ecx/edx 
        by compiler intrinsic fnuction. 

        Could you give me some example or suggestion?
Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__asm _emit` to encode x64 instructions. Additionally, since on x64 the parameters come via registers RCX and RDX need to be saved before the MOVs, then restored when accessing the parameters.

Comment: Hi Attila:
       Because of this function is used to send BIOS SMI command 
       in kernel space, so, I have to fill constant value into  
       eax/ebx/ecx/ebx before run "out" command, and get value
       from eax/ebx/ecx/edx after run "command".
       If eax/ebx can not be used before run "out" command, how do 
       I tranlate this code so that it can be run normally on x64 
       system?